# Chrome extension - Get network information

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to "read" all wireless networks through my Chrome Extension.
I found this source which answer my question: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/networking_config 
BUT in the top of the page is written:

> Important: This API works only on Chrome OS.

It is a little bit confusing.. I'm using Chrome browser on a windows 8.1 platform. Is this API action will work or not?
I'm confused because of this wiki quote:

> Chrome OS is an operating system designed by Google that is based on the Linux kernel and uses the Google Chrome web browser as its principal user interface.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS

By Wiki, the answer is Yes, each chrome browser is based on Chrome OS system so the API will work.
Please advice, Thank you in advance!
Lior.

Comment: I believe chrome os is only on chromebook laptops, the wiki is just saying that the browser is the main thing users interact with on chrome os

Comment: if you read [Google Chrome's wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome), "Google Chrome is a freeware web browser developed by Google.[15] It was first released in 2008, for Microsoft Windows, and was later ported to Linux, macOS, iOS and Android. Google Chrome is also the main component of Chrome OS, where it serves a platform for running web apps."

Comment: meaning chrome os is based on many systems but happens to be the most notable app on chrome os

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not exactly correct, this api will only work on Chrome OS.

The following words means Chrome OS uses chrome browser as its principal user interface, rather than "each chrome browser is based on Chrome OS".

> Chrome OS is an operating system designed by Google that is based on the Linux kernel and uses the Google Chrome web browser as its principal user interface.